# Rails settings environment variables on production - explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to secure my app properly by setting environment variables. I am doing it with figaro gem. I am not using heroku, just a vps I setup by myself.

Now on development all works good and makes sense. application.yml contains hardcoded database passwords which are not on database.yml anymore. application.yml is not pushed on repository and passwords are not shared. All good.

But I am having hard time making sense of it on production. If I set production section on database.yml with environment variables and then the application.yml is not on the server running on production, how can it possibly work? Or if I set them on another file that is then pushed later on repository, I just moved harcoded passwords from a file to another and are still accessible. Or are environment varibales supposed to be used only on test and development?

Could someone give me a clear explanation? I have been reading other questions and articles around but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set Unix environment variables in production. Check out [this guide](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) which states:

> Variables in the config/application.yml file will override environment variables set in the Unix shell.

In other words, in development you would set these variables in `application.yml` which would then override any values set in Unix. In production, you would set them in the shell and that is where the values would come from. I suggest doing some more general reading regarding environment variables as they are a fundamental part of application development.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. i evaluated this solution, but i was not sure first because i read some people using figaro on production (although was not really clear how) and secondly because doing this yes i move credentials outside the app, but are still available to everybody with access to server. say for instance i work with other developers or a server admin and i don't want them to have access to gmail credentials i use for mailers.

Comment: in other words i was imagining there was a way to pass credentials to production server when push and store them encrypted or similar, so that they would be visible only on my local machine. but if something like that is not possivle i will just use unix environment variables for production.

Comment: Have a look at Vault by HashiCorp. Might be what you're looking for. https://www.vaultproject.io/